# jQuery file upload restrict upload to one file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I know this question has been asked dozens of times but I can't seem to find a solution that will work for me.

I am trying to restrict the jQuery UI version of Blueimps jQuery File Upload to one file but with no success.

I have modified the input on the form to

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

I have changed the following options:

```
maxNumberOfFiles: 1
singleFileUploads: false 
limitMultiFileUploads: 1
```

Despite the settings above the script still allows the user to add multiple files and although it displays a message saying they have exceeded the upload limit, it still uploads all of the files.

Ideally I would like the list to clear whenever a new file is added so if a second file is added it simply replaces the existing file in the list.

I have tried adding `$("table tbody.files").empty();` as a call back to the add function but all this does is remove the previous file from the visible list, when the user clicks upload it still uploads all the files the user has added.

Comment: If we may, May we see the code for that?

Comment: @eeya which part, there are about 6 individual files belonging to the Blueimp jQuery file upload

Comment: On how you've called the [upload] file when user can add multiple files.